# some standard notation for $\Delta x + \Delta y$

Tags: notation

is there any appropriate name (preferable a conventional one if it exists) I can give to something referring to $\Delta x + \Delta y$ where each represents the total distance from a point to each edge of an enclosing frame in both the $x$ and $y$ dimensions?

I just want to know if there's one such notation

[image showing what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO0nq.png)

I am referring to $\Delta x$ for example as the sum of the distances from the point to both the left and right edges, so $\Delta x = x_1 + x_2$ and $\Delta y = y_1+y_2$ in the image.

Comment: if I understand correctly, $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ should actually be constant quantities as soon as the point is inside the frame, and they would be equal to the x-dimension and the y-dimension of the box, so there is no need for any special notation.

Comment: Correct, but my question specifically asks for one. I happen to require an appropriate name for the sum of distances in both dimensions.

Comment: That's the sum of the taxicab distances of frame vertices from the point, i.e. $\sum_{v\in V}\Vert p-v\Vert_1$ with $p$ the point and $V$ the set of frame vertices.

Comment: @J.G. I see. Very well then.